# ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource For SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, reporting-services

I am trying to access reporting server in my Azure WebSite. Reporting server is installed in a VM on azure and I can access the reporting server over internet(I have tested the reporting server url in IE and it works find with the credentials provided). But When I try to access the reporting server in my web app. It is giving me following error

```
    ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access
rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity 
(typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the 
configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not 
impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the 
identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request 
user.
```

Web App works fine when tested on local servers(Reporting server and web server are two different machines in our local environment but they are on same domain).

I am unable to figure out what is the issue.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the exact reason, But I changed the ReportViewer from 9.0 to 10.0 and now it is working.